# Compatibility between motherboard and ssd

Tags: windows, memory, cpu, hardware-rec

I have a motherboard Gigabyte GA-H61M-S1. It's very old and it was prebuilt. I need to put a SSD for it to boost faster and for my work. The problem is that I don't really know which SSD is compatible with my motherboard.

- It has a bunch of SATA ports but is that enough to know that it supports an SSD?

Also, im not planning on buying a 1TB SSD. Just something for it to boost windows faster like idk 250GB or even 128 GB SSD.

Comment: “It has a bunch of SATA ports but is that enough to know that it supports an SSD?” All SATA ports support SSD drives. Just purchase an SSD and connect it to a SATA cable and that’s that.

Answer (score 0):

Your board has SATA2 ports (3 gigabit/sec, that is 375 Mb/s max, but actual speeds will be lower). SATA3 is reverse-compatible with that, so you can get any modern SATA SSD that you like (most of these are in 2.5" laptop sata hdd form-factor).
If your goal is speed - just stay away from the cheapest ones and read benchmarks.

Your board has PCIe slots, so it's physically possible to install an NVMe ssd via an adapter, but older MBs cannot boot from these without severe bios trickery and in most cases it is not worth the effort.